# Ajax - How to pass to view an array of javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Inside my Ajax function I have an array of data. It has come from a Laravel controller. Here is the result of doing a console log on the data array of objects:

```
0:      category_id: 60
            parent_id: "58"
            price: "100.00"
            product_id: "abc6798"
            product_name: "Install Rubber"

1:      name: "Installation"
        parent_id: "57"
```

I now need to populate my view with the results of that array. As an array with one index, everything works fine, using the code below, But with two indices I can not get the value of 'name'. When I try I get  an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Here is the code I use to render the values onto my view:

```
 response($.map(data, function (object) {           //this works with 1 index
                            return {
                                label: object.product_name,
                                value: object.product_id,
                                price: object.price,
                                name:object[1].name,        // Here is the problem using second index
                            };
                        }));

select: function (event, ui) {                           //this works with 1 index
                $(' .product_name ').val(ui.item.label);
                $(' .price').val(ui.item.price);
                $(' .product_id ').val(ui.item.value);
                $(' .name').val(ui.item.name);       // Here is the problem using second index
                return false;
            }
```

I have searched through SO and have tried using "flatten()", "Map()" and also just using the simple `object[1].value`, as shown below. But so far nothing has worked for me - what am I missing? Many Thanks!

Comment: It seems your data array of objects has a non uniform data. How does the input array look like as a valid js object?

Comment: @ITgoldman - Thanks for helping out. Sorry I am a little lost by your question. I have passed an array from a Laravel controller using json_encode()

When I do a debug of the resulting array I get this, see this pastebin
https://pastebin.com/3Df8tVkg. 

That is passed to the Ajax AutoComplete using this function: echo json_encode($productParent);

Comment: Are there going to be only 2 items? How can you flatten them if they have conflicting keys such `parent_id`?